# Django - F('datetimefield') + relativedelta(months=1) fails

Tags: python, django, python-dateutil, relativedelta

**I am trying to update a self datetime field of a model using F() object in django.**

```
HeatWatchList.objects.filter(
    user=request.user,
    next_date_to__lt=datetime.combine(datetime.now().date(), time.min)
).update(
    next_date_from = F('next_date_from') + relativedelta(months=1),
    next_date_to = F('next_date_to') + relativedelta(months=1)
)
```

But when doing this i got `AttributeError: relativedelta object has no attribute translate`.

Here is the traceback i got when executing the code maybe it has an issue using the F() object when adding value with a datetime type relativedelta.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 83, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 477, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 437, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 474, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\farm_management\heat\views.py", line 192, in update_watchlist
    next_date_to = F('next_date_to') + relativedelta(months=1)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 637, in update
    rows = query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1148, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 835, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 110, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 164, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 143, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 118, in _escape_args
    return tuple(conn.literal(arg) for arg in args)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 118, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(conn.literal(arg) for arg in args)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 800, in literal
    return self.escape(obj, self.encoders)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 793, in escape
    return escape_item(obj, self.charset, mapping=mapping)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\pymysql\converters.py", line 27, in escape_item
    val = encoder(val, mapping)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\pymysql\converters.py", line 110, in escape_unicode
    return u"'%s'" % _escape_unicode(value)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\Envs\djangular\lib\site-packages\pymysql\converters.py", line 73, in _escape_unicode
    return value.translate(_escape_table)
AttributeError: 'relativedelta' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

Comment: That code doesn't give you that error. Show the whole code, along with the full traceback.

Comment: Just a moment sir

Comment: @DanielRoseman i just updated my question with traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like pymysql's converters [does not support](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/converters.py#L364) relativedelta objects.
One possible solution is to iterate over objects and update it (inefficient):

```
objects_list = HeatWatchList.objects.filter(
user=request.user,
next_date_to__lt=datetime.combine(datetime.now().date(), time.min)
)

for obj in object_list:
    obj.next_date_from = onj.next_date_from + relativedelta(months=1)
    obj.next_date_to = onj.next_date_to + relativedelta(months=1)
    objsave()
```

Or better use `datetime.timedelta` instead of `relativedelta` if it possible:

```
HeatWatchList.objects.filter(
user=request.user,
next_date_to__lt=datetime.combine(datetime.now().date(), time.min)
).update(
next_date_from = F('next_date_from') + timedelta(days=31),
next_date_to = F('next_date_to') + timedelta(days=31)
)
```

Comment: thanks for giving anwer, but i heard that timedelta doesnt yield accurate datetime value and because of that many prefers to use relativedelta instead is that true? Thanks!

Comment: but hopefully pymysql will support this one. how could they leave such useful function?

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab yes its true, you cannot for example set timedelta as month, you only have days as an option. But I dont see any other solution:(

Comment: Its fine for me then, fortunately the system will be according to days not as month after inquiring here. this might be still a good solution but i hope pymysql will support relativedelta object.

Comment: But wait i already tried adding a value from relativedelta when the first time creating the instance. but it will not only works with F() object

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab yes if you'll update each instance separately then relativedelta also work fine.